# Installing node on Windows - AWS Codebuild

Tags: aws-codebuild

I'm running a codebuild build server based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

During the install phase, I'm installing nodejs with Chocolatey:

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
      - Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
      - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install nodejs-lts -y
      - refreshenv
      - node -v
```

After installation, node still shows up as missing:

```
nodejs-lts has been installed.
  nodejs-lts may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of nodejs-lts was successful.
  Software installed as 'MSI', install location is likely default.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait...Finished..
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

However, it does work if it is all chained into a single line:

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
      - Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"; C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install nodejs-lts -y; refreshenv; node -v
```

How can node be made available on subsequent commands?

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite - codebuild is a slightly different scenario in that the normal 'restart powershell' or 'update your environmental variables in the windows gui' don't apply here.  It is my understanding that refreshenv is meant to reload environmental variables.  I would add that this is not an issue on any normal windows environments - just within codebuild.